# Scanner не игнорирует дефис

Tags: java, scanner

Необходимо ввести 10 id студентов и их оценок через дефис (1001-40 1002-50 ...)

```
List<Student> st = new ArrayList<Student>();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
sc.useDelimiter("-");
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
int id = sc.nextInt();
int score = sc.nextInt();
st.add(new Student(id, score));
}
```

Программа выдает ошибку. Ввод с консоли:

```
1011-40
1002-50
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
at SortScore.main(SortScore.java:20)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Происходит следующее.

Выражением `sc.useDelimiter("-");` вы задаете в качестве разделителя [регулярное выражение](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) `"-"`.

`Scanner` считывает первое число `1011`, считывает символ `"-"`, но второе число считать не может, т.к. сразу за ним следует символ перевода строки, а он теперь не считается разделителем (вы же переопределили разделитель).

Соответственно, в регулярке надо учесть возможность появления символа переноса строки. Например, так:

```
sc.useDelimiter("[-\\n]");
```

Или так

```
sc.useDelimiter("[-\\s]");
```

В последнем случае вы сможете отделять пары чисел друг от друга не только enter-ом, но и пробелом.